# How can I set a MySQL database to use MyISAM by default?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server which has it's default storage engine set as InnoDB.  I have a project which requires the tables in the database to be MyISAM.  I'd like to create my database with a flag to set the default storage engine to be MyISAM.  Is this possible without changing the server default and also without manually specifying each table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDITED:
Actually, yes - a global variable [default-storage-engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine) can be changed only for a session, so

```
SET storage_engine=MYISAM;    
SET table_type=BDB;
```

will affect only the current session. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html) for details.

Comment: @hellsgate, read the faq (in short - vote up *all* useful answers, accept the best solution p.s. you can change the accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

see this here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,26193,26193
you can change your database to MyISAM -- I'm guessing you're only reading from the tables in the database (otherwise if you have read/write transactions InnoDB is the better choice).